# How to plot a graph ontop of another graph in App Designer?

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

In app designer (MATLAB) I have two graphs I want to display ontop of eachother. This is what i did:

```
plot(app.UIAxes,(1:length(app.var.OEch))/app.var.OE_Fs,app.var.OEch,'Color',[0,0.7,0.9])

st=app.var.st;
hold on
for ss = 1:length(st)
plot(app.UIAxes,[st(ss);st(ss)],[50;250], 'r');
end
hold off
```

If I were to get rid of the app.UIAxes in the for loop, it would work and graph both graphs separately, but I want it to be able to graph it on the UIAxes. Currently, I just see a white screen where my plotted graph should be if I were to run this.

Comment: As a general rule: it's best to pass an axes hand to `hold`. Other than that, the fail-safe way to do this would be to call `plot` just once: `plot(hAx, x1, y1, x2, y2, ....)`.

Comment: Would hax be UIAxes in this case? And I can't really call plot just once because I have a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `hold on` with `hold(app.UIAxes, 'on');`

```
hold(app.UIAxes, 'on');
for ss = 1:length(st)
    plot(app.UIAxes,[st(ss);st(ss)],[50;250], 'r');
end
hold(app.UIAxes, 'off');

%Add drawnow command (just in case...).
drawnow
```

The reason you need to use `hold(app.UIAxes, 'on');`, is that `hold on` applies "current axes", and in GUI application, the focus may change to other axes (when you have more than one axes).

Example using `hold on`:
[image]

Example using `hold(app.UIAxes, 'on')`:
[image]